# UIVibrancyEffect UIVisualEffectView subview isn't vibrant enough

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios8

We have successfully integrated UIVibrancyEffect and UIVisualEffectView into our app, but I'm noticing that the vibrancy isn't as intense as I'd like and the text is more dim than the demos I've seen. I can't find any way to tweak this, or to affect it in any way. I thought it might be because we are using a custom font, but I tried that too and the font is thicker but still looks dim. Any ideas?

With our custom font Open Sans Light:

[image: screenshot of our custom font (open sans light)]

With system font:

[image: screenshot with system font]

Here is the code:

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
[blurEffectView setFrame:self.viewController.view.bounds];

UIVisualEffect *vibrancyEffect = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:blurEffect];
UIVisualEffectView *vibrancyEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:vibrancyEffect];
[vibrancyEffectView setFrame:self.viewController.view.bounds];


[blurEffectView.contentView addSubview:vibrancyEffectView];


UITextView *messageText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)];
[messageText setFont:[CLAppearanceManager fontForLabelType:CLAppearanceLabelFontWaveMessageEntry]];
[messageText setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
messageText.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
messageText.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0,1.0);
messageText.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
[messageText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
if(self.messageLabel.text && self.messageLabel.text.length>0) {
    [messageText setText:self.messageLabel.text];
} else {
    [messageText setText:@"no message"];
}
[messageText setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[messageText setEditable:NO];
[messageText addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];

self.bigMessageText = messageText;
[vibrancyEffectView.contentView addSubview:messageText];
self.blurView = blurEffectView;

UITapGestureRecognizer *dismiss = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeBlurView)];
[self.blurView addGestureRecognizer:dismiss];
[self.viewController.view addSubview:self.blurView];
[self.class centerContentForTextView:messageText];
[self.blurView setAlpha:0.0];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    [self.blurView setAlpha:1.0];
} completion:nil
}];
```

Comment: Please go into more detail about how you’re setting up your view hierarchy, especially the blur effect view and vibrancy effect view.

Answer (score 4):

Although the [documentation suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIVibrancyEffect/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIVibrancyEffect/notificationCenterVibrancyEffect) you use the same `UIVisualEffect` as the `UIVisualEffectView`:

> When you create a new vibrancy effect, use the same UIBlurEffect that
>   you used to create the blur view. Using a different UIBlurEffect can
>   cause unwanted visual effect combinations.

I would recommend setting your `UIVibrancyEffect` to `UIBlurEffectStyleLight`:

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
[blurEffectView setFrame:self.viewController.view.bounds];

UIBlurEffect *vibrancyBlurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffect *vibrancyEffect = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:vibrancyBlurEffect];
UIVisualEffectView *vibrancyEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:vibrancyEffect];
[vibrancyEffectView setFrame:self.viewController.view.bounds];
[blurEffectView.contentView addSubview:vibrancyEffectView];
```

Comment: Weird, I was having the same issue. I tried your solution, now the text is completely black. But on "Debug View hierarchy" it appears white. I'm on iOS 13

Comment: This is likely due to the new [Dark Mode introduced in iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/).

Answer (score 1):

Add Exactly same Label/TextView to `vibrancyEffectView` (not contentView)

The Label/TextView should have a `alpha` less than 1.0. I kept it 0.5. You Can Try any other Value.

Comment: as of iOS 13 it will produce crash with warning stating that views should be added do UIVisualEffectView's contentView.

Comment: That’s still fine, you may add the views behind vibrancy view. Though, in iOS 13 I don’t think there’s such need due to introduction of new vibrancy styles.